# Install numpy on server

Tags: python, numpy, openblas

I have a shared server on namecheap.

Baiscally I am need to run a script on it. (I need to call that using android,that's second part.)

What I did was to install `miniconda` on my server.

If i execute `conda list` , I get the following.

```
[iamaoxdo@server188 cgi-bin]$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/iamaoxdo/public_html/miniconda2:
#
conda                     3.19.0                   py27_0
conda-env                 2.4.5                    py27_0
cython                    0.23.4                   py27_0
libgfortran               1.0                           0
numpy                     1.10.2                   py27_0
openblas                  0.2.14                        3
openssl                   1.0.2f                        0
pandas                    0.17.1              np110py27_0
pip                       8.0.1                    py27_0
pycosat                   0.6.1                    py27_0
pycrypto                  2.6.1                    py27_0
python                    2.7.11                        0
python-dateutil           2.4.2                    py27_0
pytz                      2015.7                   py27_0
pyyaml                    3.11                     py27_1
readline                  6.2                           2
requests                  2.9.1                    py27_0
setuptools                19.4                     py27_0
six                       1.10.0                   py27_0
sqlite                    3.9.2                         0
tk                        8.5.18                        0
wheel                     0.26.0                   py27_1
yaml                      0.1.6                         0
zlib                      1.2.8                         0
```

This basically tells that it's installed on my server.

Btw, I have also created a environment as explained in their [guide](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#running-the-test-suite).

Now the problem is that I can't import `numpy` library(My main goal is to import `pandas` library but I figured that it's dependent on `numpy`).

I have a simple file named `servertest.py` contents of which are as follows.

```
#!/usr/public_html/miniconda2/envs/pythonenv/lib/python2.7
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# enable debugging
import cgitb
import sys
sys.path.append("/user/include/numpy")
cgitb.enable()
#import nltk

import numpy
print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"

print("Hello2")
print sys.version_info[0]
print sys.version_info[1]
import site
#print site.getsitepackages()
#print sys.modules.keys()
print sys.path
```

When I run it, I get the following error

```
(pythonenv)[iamaoxdo@server188 cgi-bin]$ python servertest.py
OpenBLAS: pthread_creat error in blas_thread_init function. Error code:11
```

I even tried re-installing all three packages i.e `openblas,numpy,pandas`.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here? How can I make it work.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new conda env with numpy in it e.g. "conda create --name myenv numpy" then running against that?

Comment: Yeah, if you see the last statement, you will see `pythonenv` at the beginning. that's the environment which I created.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using openblas?  You have numpy.linalg.  Removing openblas might be a fix.